# When I run the view_inventory function after appending to the list, the appending item doesn't show

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, class, instance

```
class Character(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.inventory = []

    def add_inventory(self, item):
        self.inventory.append(item)

    def view_inventory(self):
        for i in range(len(self.inventory)):
            print "%r. %s" % (i+1, self.inventory[i])


class Hero(Character):

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.inventory = ["Torch", "Wrench", "Laser Cannon"]

Hero().view_inventory()
Hero().add_inventory("Key")
Hero().view_inventory()
```

I've tested the inventory instance after appending to it with the add_inventory function which shows "Key" as added to the end of the inventory list, however both Hero().view_inventory() print out the same results, without Key included.

Comment: What you have there is 3 different `Hero` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by vaultah, you are creating three separate `Hero` instances. Change as follows:

```
hero = Hero()  # create one Hero instance
hero.view_inventory()  # and make the method calls on this very instance
hero.add_inventory("Key")
hero.view_inventory()
```